# Modify the value of a variable outside callback with the callback inside loop

Tags: node.js, callback

I am new to Nodejs and I am facing with a problem: Modify the value of a variable outside callback with the callback inside a loop.

I am coding online-judgle project, this is my function to check output of a program with answer from database. I created result object to store amount of correct testcase.

```
function compareResult(fileName, problem, timeLimit, callback) {
        const cp = require('child_process');
        const exePath = 'submit\\' + fileName + '.exe';
        const child = cp.spawn(exePath, ['--from=markdown', '--to=html'], {timeout: timeLimit});
        MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, db) {
            if (err) throw err;
            var dbo = db.db(dbName);
            var query = { id_problem: problem, is_eg: "false" };
            var proj = { projection: {input: 1, output: 1} };
            dbo.collection("sample").find(query, proj).toArray(function(err, arr) {
                if (err) throw err;
                if (arr != null) {

                    var result = {
                        correct: 0,
                        total: arr.length
                    };

                    for (const json of arr) {
                        const answer = json['output'];
                        child.stdin.write(json['input']);
                        child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
                            if (data == answer) { 
                                result.correct += 1; // I want to modify result object here.
                            }
                        });
                        child.stdin.end();
                    };
                    console.log(result);
                    callback(result);
                }
            });
        });
```

I want to modify result object in that place. How will I do it?

Comment: What problem are you encountering?

Comment: Why are you putting the asynchronous, non-blocking `child.stdout.on('data', ...)` inside a `for` loop?  That means you will end up with a whole bunch of identical event handlers all listening for the exact same events and they will all fire.  This clearly cannot work properly.  For us to be able to help, you need to show more of the real code so we can see enough of the real problem to see what you're really trying to accomplish.  **Do not write questions here with pseudo-code like this.**  Show us your real code so we can see the real problem.

Comment: FYI, this code will indeed modify `result.correct` just fine, but it has so many other problems that it likely will not solve whatever problem you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: This needs a fairly significant redesign.   `child.stdout.on(...)` is non-blocking, so all your `for` loop does is just attach a whole bunch of those listeners and it calls all the `child.stdin.write()` statements at once too.  And, you're calling `callback(result)` BEFORE any of the items have completed (again because it's non-blocking, asynchronous).

Comment: FYI, the `readline` [module](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) is typically used to prompt for info from the user.  In newish versions of nodejs, it even has a promise interface.

Answer (score -2):

```js
function compareResult(fileName, problem, timeLimit, callback) {
    const cp = require('child_process');
    const exePath = 'submit\\' + fileName + '.exe';
    const child = cp.spawn(exePath, ['--from=markdown', '--to=html'], {timeout: timeLimit});
    MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db(dbName);
        var query = { id_problem: problem, is_eg: "false" };
        var proj = { projection: {input: 1, output: 1} };
        dbo.collection("sample").find(query, proj).toArray(function(err, arr) {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (arr != null) {

                var result = {
                    correct: 0,
                    total: arr.length
                };

                for (const json of arr) {
                    const answer = json['output'];
                    child.stdin.write(json['input']);
                    child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
                        if (data == answer) { 
                            result.correct += 1; 
                        }
                        // Decrement total here to track how many 'data' events have been emitted
                        result.total--; 
                        if (result.total === 0) {
                            // All 'data' events have been emitted, so call the callback function
                            callback(result);
                        }
                    });
                    child.stdin.end();
                };
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I use (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) and add condition if (i == arr.length - 1) and it works :D.

Comment: **How can this possibly work properly?**  You're doing all the writes at once and installing a whole bunch of simultaneous `child.stdout.on('data', ...)` event handlers.  Yes, this will tell you when the last event handler is done, but it won't get you each answer individually.  It will just get you N copies of the first answer.  I have no idea why the OP marked this as accepted because I don't see how it can possibly  work.

Comment: A better solution direction is to convert ALL the asynchronous operations here to use promises and then you can use `await` to properly serialize them and the `for` loop will work how you intend.  The database already has a promise interface.  The readline module for getting info from the user already  has a promise interface.